# Passing char* array to function

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have an array of char with 4 names.

```
char* c[8] = {"Dave", "Alex", "John", "Andrew"};
sort_array(c, 4);
```

I need to sort these names by alphabetical order. I am trying to receive this array in a function like:

```
void sort_array(char* arr, int n) {
    ...codehere...
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
cannot convert 'char**' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'void
sort_array(char*, int)'
```

So, how to get rid of this error?

Comment: Your function takes a `char *`, i.e. a C-style string.  You're trying to give it multiple strings...

Comment: You should use char * a[] or char** a . arrays name actually is the first elements pointers name. For example (a[1]==(a++)) you should look c++ tutorials or books at first.

Answer (score 3):

A C-String--what you have an array of--is really just an array of characters, which you can look at as either `char c[]` or `char *c`. Since you have an **array** of c-strings, your parameter will either have to be `char **c` or `char *c[]`, so your function would be:

```
void sort_array(char* arr[], int n) {
   //...codehere...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're passing in an array of Strings (char[]), It should be

```
void sort_array(char** arr, int n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function must take `char **arr` as a parametr.

```
void sort_array(char **arr, int n) {
...codehere...
}
```

Why? Because, `char *` is only one string (pointer to first character of it). If you want to pass array of ints to function, you use `int *arg` argument. If you want array of strings, you use `char **arg`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the array shall be defined as

```
const char * c[8] = {"Dave", "Alex", "John", "Andrew"};
```

because it is an array of pointers that point to string literals (the first characters of string literals). String literals may not be changed.

That do not make the error as you did you could define the function the following way

```
void sort_array( const char* arr[], int n );
```

In this case you may call it as

```
sort_array(c, 4);
```